# How to remove an entire array in mongodb- node

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

This is what I tred

```
removeFromCart:(userId)=>{
        return new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=>{
            db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION).updateOne({_id:userId},
                {
                    $pull:{
                        products
                    }
                }
            )
            resolve(response)
        })
    }
```

This is the structure of my database, after placing the orde, I have to remove the cart array , Then what I have to do?

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "633abca2f9a57f6470904812"
  },
  "user": {
    "$oid": "633ab3c11e6e97b6332f56a1"
  },
  "products": [
    {
      "item": {
        "$oid": "63314b0c07e279ee33c55caf"
      },
      "quantity": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$unset` [operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/):

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "633abca2f9a57f6470904812"
},
{
  "$unset": {
    "products": ""
  }
})
```

Here's an example on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/X9jEnmKjCGK